# How can I prepend an onclick event with a string of text

Tags: javascript, jquery, onclick, anchor, prepend

I have `<a>`s with onclick events:

```
<a href="#" onclick="window.open('TrackPackage.asp', '', 'location=1,menubar=1,scrollbars=1,status=1,resizable=1,width=635,height=460'); return false;" class="nounderline">Track Your Package »</a>
```

How can I prepend those onclick events with `http://www.example.com` so that the result will be:

```
<a href="#" onclick="window.open('http://www.example.com/TrackPackage.asp', '', 'location=1,menubar=1,scrollbars=1,status=1,resizable=1,width=635,height=460'); return false;" class="nounderline">Track Your Package »</a>
```

It has to be compatible with jQuery 1.4.2

Somebody else, had mentioned something like this, but I can't get it to work in 1.4.2:

```
var link = $("a"); // I don't have enough info to tell you how to precisely get this instance
var originalOnClick = link.attr("onclick");
var part1 = "window.open('"; // this is always the same, right?
var part2 = originalOnClick.substr(part1.length); // the remainder, beginning with TrackPackage.asp
var newOnClick = part1 + "http://www.example.com/" + part2;

link.attr("onclick", newOnClick);
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think `window.open()` is a good idea here. It will get blocked by most popup blockers and if you're using jQuery you shouldn't be using the inline `onclick` event anyway.
What you're trying to do can probably be achieved with a simple anchor link:

```
<a href="trackPackage.asp" target="_blank"></a>
```

And then you can do something like this:

```
var prependUrl = function($link, url) {
    var oldUrl = $link.attr('href'),
        newUrl = url + oldUrl;
    $link.attr('href', newUrl);
}

prependUrl($('#yourLink'), 'http://www.example.com/');
```

**EDIT:**

If you don't have control over the html and you need to do it like that then use `replace()` on the `onClick` attribute like:

```
$('a').attr('onClick', $('a').attr('onClick').replace('window.open(\'', 'window.open(\'http://example.com/'));
```

**example:** http://jsfiddle.net/elclanrs/AH4As/

Comment: I have no control over the HTML if I did, I would've used `target="_blank"` a very long time ago...

Comment: Well, it does work, you'll have to work on your own function that changes the attribute.

Comment: What do you mean here's the fiddle?

Comment: There! `$('a').attr('onclick', $('a').attr('onclick').replace('window.open(\'', 'window.open(\'http://example.com/'));`

Comment: How can I get that to work with jQuery 1.4.2 or 1.4.4 in jsFiddle

Comment: Just select **jQuery 1.4.4** from the "Choose Framwork" dropdown.

Comment: I know but the JavaScript does not work when I do. I'm using 1.4.2 on my site

Comment: Just put capital "C" on `onclick` so, `onClick`. It should work. See edit.

Comment: You forgot the second `onClick`...Man you have no interest in solving this I see...

Comment: I'm actually getting an error when I insert this code into my site, it says `undefined is not an object when evaluating $('a').attr('onClick').replace)`